# Why is 1. x (Times[1.`, x]) not simplified to x?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerical-value

This is maybe a silly question, but I could not think of any logical reason why it is not simplified automatically.

I was working with a big linear equation system with some constrained inequalities and noticed a lot of "1. xyz" terms.

I tried `Simplify[1. x == x]` which gives `True`, but `1. x` stays `1. x`. I'm using the simple rule `Rule[1., 1]` to simplify the "1. xyz" terms in my equation system; it just looks somehow "better" (in my opinion).

Function `Times` was last modified in version 3, so this behaviour should exist for a long time now.

What is the logical reason behind?

Comment: This has been asked more than once before but I can't find it.  In short, `1.` is an [inexact](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html) number, i.e. not `1`, just an approximation of `1` with an associated precision.   `1. x` won't simplify to `x==1*x` because it is only approximately equal to it. In most cases it's better not to use inexact numbers for symbolic calculations.

Comment: You can `Round` or `Rationalize` the result to an appropriate precision to eliminate 1. or 0. inexact coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalization of your rule approach:

```
  {1., 2.5, 5, 1.0001, 2.9999999999999999} /. {x_?MachineNumberQ /; 
                                              Chop[Abs[Round[x] - x]] == 0 :> Round[x]}
```

> {1, 2.5, 5, 1.0001, 3}

Note `Chop[]` is not strictly necessary but serves as a reminder we are doing a floating point approximate comparison (and you can specify a non-default tolerance if you want )

Answer (score 4):

The comments already point out that for a general symbol like `x` it wouldn't be justified to replace `1. x` by `x`. The reason is that `x` is unknown and therefore generically could be an exact number for which multiplication by an inexact number (`1.`) would violate the equality.

So you should tell *Mathematica* that your variable `x` is restricted to values for which it's OK to multiply by `1.` without worrying about  potential change from exact to inexact. Here is one way to do this:

```
x /: 1. x := x
```

This says the same thing as you expressed in your rule, but it associates this rule only with the variable `x` so that the replacement is not inadvertently done somewhere else in a big expression where it may not be allowed.

Here is a test:

```
1. x

(* ==> x *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments; `1. == 1` is `True`, but `1. === 1` (`SameQ`) is `False`. I will stay with my rule, because `Rationalize` will modify my whole equation system and I would like to keep it at machine precission.

Comment: After `Rationalize` has handled all of the 1. and 0. coefficients, you can use N to return the remaining coefficients to machine precision.

Comment: This answer should be a comment below your own question.