# How do I to remove a factor of 1

Tags: numerical-value

I evaluated

```
Subscript[ε, 1, 2] = 0.5 Subscript[γ, 1, 2]
2 μ Subscript[ε, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> 1. μ Subscript[γ, 1, 2]
> ```

How do I to remove the factor `1.`?

Comment: Related: [(2496)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2496/121), [(7463)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7463/121), [(8104)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8104/121), [(50721)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50721/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Subscript[ε, 1, 2] = .5 Subscript[γ, 1, 2]
```

> 0.5 Subscript[γ, 1, 2]

```
Rationalize[2 μ Subscript[ε, 1, 2]]
```

> μ Subscript[γ, 1, 2]

```
% // TeXForm
```

> $\mu  \gamma _{1,2}$

Or, use `1/2` instead of `0.5` in your first line:

```
Subscript[ε, 1, 2] = 1/2 Subscript[γ, 1, 2]
```

> Subscript[γ, 1, 2]/2

```
2 μ Subscript[ε, 1, 2]
```

> μ Subscript[γ, 1, 2]

Comment: thanks, but why we can not directly use 0.5??

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, `2 * 0.5` gives `1.` and you don't want that. Btw,  compare `1 * something` with `1. * something`

Comment: @kglr would you consider this a duplicate of any of the Linked questions?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the last one seems like a duplicate.

Comment: Good to know, it is duplicate! thank you @Mr.Wizard.